Javascript daylight saving for Google Tag Manager firing trigger
I'm using the below to fire a webchat tag only from 9-5, however when we move to BST it's one hour out:
function () {
 // GMT
 // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/...
 var timezone = 'GMT'
 var localTime = new Date();
 var time = new Date(localTime.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: timezone}));
 return time.getHours();
}

Does anyone know of a way for it to detect daylight saving and update to BST please?
Thanks.
